# Functions and return in OOP

Tags: objective-c

I'm currently trying to learn Objective C and by this way, Oriented Object languages.

I'm declaring variables from a class I've written, but, my functions are way too long, and I'd like to cut that code off.

I do not know how the return works with classes and that's my problem.

```
    Grapejuice *juice;
    juice = [[Grapejuice alloc] init];
    [juice setName:@"Grape juice"];
    [juice setOrderNumber:1000];
    [juice setPrice:1.79];
```

This, is part of a main in which I'm doing this to several objects, how can I do that in a separated function, and still got these informations out of this new function to be re-used later (to be printed for example) ? 
Not sure if I'm clear but I've just started learning it yesterday, still hesitating on the basics.

Thanks homies.

Comment: `Grapejuice *make_juice() { return [[Grapejuice alloc] init]; }`?

Comment: The point is to cut the whole code I gave you onto a separated function, not just the initialization line

Comment: yeah, I understand. I thought the above example was enough, but since it apparently isn't, I seem to have to spell out the whole thing: `Grapejuice *make_juice() { Grapejuice *juice = [[Grapejuice alloc] init]; [juice setPrice:1.79]; /* etc. */ return juice; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I believe what you want is a custom "init" method for your `Grapejuice` class.

In Grapejuice.h, add:

```
- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name orderNumber:(NSInteger)number price:(double)price;
```

In Grapejuice.m, add:

```
- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name orderNumber:(NSInteger)number price:(double)price {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _name = name;
        _orderNumber = number;
        _price = price;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Then to use that code you do:

```
Grapejuice *juice = [[Grapejuice alloc] initWithName:@"Grape Juice" orderNumber:1000 price:1.79];
```

Please note that you may need to adjust the data types for the `orderNumber` and `price` parameters. I'm just guessing. Adjust them appropriately based on whatever type you specified for the corresponding properties you have on your `Grapejuice` class.

Comment: I came back today to say that I did a custom init and it works perfectly, figured it out yesterday. Thanks for your help !
Just one thing, why would I use a NSInteger instead of a standard int ?